# How to calculate cardinal direction from EXIF lat/long reference point?

Tags: geolocation, geospatial

I'm parsing EXIF data from some drone footage, and unfortunately it does not include `GPSImgDirection` or `FlightYaw` which would give me cardinal "compass" direction.  This is the only EXIF GPS data that is given:

```
exif:GPSAltitude: 346315/1000
exif:GPSInfo: 31656
exif:GPSLatitude: 41/1, 18/1, 137576/10000
exif:GPSLatitudeRef: N
exif:GPSLongitude: 81/1, 45/1, 16792/10000
exif:GPSLongitudeRef: W
```

I know I could grab the next frame in the footage and compare GPS points to get direction, but I wanted to double check with people smarter than me:

Is it possible to calculate cardinal direction with only the information provided below?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (that I can think of) to get the "look angle" from a single point.

If you know the orientation of the camera to the drone and it's next (or previous) location you can calculate it.